# How can I flatten this json with python and pandas?

Tags: python, json, pandas

I am trying with this code but doesn't work for me, I want to flat all, thanks in advance.

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize    
data = json.load(data.json)
df = json_normalize(data, [ '1.0',"email",['password']])
```

if i try this one,

```
df = json_normalize(data, [ '1.0',["password"]]),
```

i only can get the paasword, but i try this one

```
df = json_normalize(data, [ '1.0',"email",['password']]),
```

this is the error TypeError: string indices must be integers

This is the sample of my json:

```
{
    "1.0": [{
            "edit_distance": [
                0,
                1
            ],
            "email": "a@gmail.com",
            "password": [
                "123123123",
                "1231232"
            ]
        },
        {
            "edit_distance": [
                0,
                1
            ],
            "email": "b@c.com",
            "password": [
                "123123",
                "123123"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to flatten the JSON? (flap?). What would you like the end result to look like? What doesn't work for you in your current code? Is it too slow? How slow? Do you get an error? Does it not return the results you expect?

Comment: if i try this one, df = json_normalize(data, [ '1.0',["password"]]), i only can get the paasword, but i try this onedf = json_normalize(data, [ '1.0',"email",['password']]), this is the error TypeError: string indices must be integers, thanks

Comment: Don't just tell me @testeo. Tell everyone! [edit] your question to include what's actually happening and what you would like to happen instead..

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want the three keys in the list of dictionaries to be the columns. You were very close.

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize    
data = json.load(data.json)
df = json_normalize(data, ['1.0',]) # the path to your records is '1.0'
                                    # and it gives us a list of dicts/records.
```

Yields:

```
edit_distance   email       password
[0, 1]          a@gmail.com [123123123, 1231232]
[0, 1]          b@c.com     [123123, 123123]
```